# Refreshing SUDOKU solver

Tags: c#, multithreading, sudoku

I made a SUDOKU solver. When is solve a number it should be written to the screen but it's happen only when the solver is done. Why only then the screen is refreshing when it is done?

ii is the number, jj is the row, ll is the column

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Thread tr2 = new Thread(adatbszal);
    tr2.Start();
}

private void adatbszal()
{
    while (fut)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        if (adat[jj, ll] != 0)
        {
            SetText(jj, ll, adat[jj, ll].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            SetText(jj, ll, "");
        }
    }
}

private void SetText(int i, int j, string adat2)
{
    if (adatB[i,j].InvokeRequired)
    {
        valami d = new valami(SetText);
        Invoke(d, new object[] { i, j, adat2 });
    }
    else
    {
        adatB[i, j].Text = adat2;
    }
}
...
Thread th = new Thread(solver);
th.Start();
```

full project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZTA4Ledfwl3romBY2UTvUoU9MZfY35g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is `valami`?

Comment: delegate void valami(int i, int j, string adat2);

Comment: How are you testing this? I get IndexOutOfRangeException on the line `jj = elozmeny[d, 0];` whenever I click Solve. (d=-1)

Comment: When I click Random and then Solve / Megold, it is animating, showing many numbers. So I need more specific instructions on how you are seeing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a breakpoint on `Invoke(d, new object[] { i, j, adat2 });` to verify that it is being reached, and when it is, add a breakpoint to `if (adatB[i,j].InvokeRequired)` before stepping, then make sure that the same parameters are being received to verify that the `Invoke` is triggering `SetText` as expected. (Step Into would be simpler, but I'm not sure that would work on an Invoke Line.)

If all that is working, then check if the display updates then `adatB[i, j].Text = adat2;` executes in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is updating the display like you want it to, but it's not working properly in other regards. In one of my tests, it is just setting the first cell to "2" over and over again, so you won't see any change. You need to verify that the code is doing the right work before you verify that the display is updating properly. I think you may see many problems from having 3 threads running simultaneously which can all update or read the same global values when other threads are assuming these values (like `jj`) are not changing between lines. I would suggest not sharing data between threads if you are not very experienced with multi-threaded programming. Perhaps you can re-implement this as a single-threaded program that calls an update function periodically instead.